# Replacement of Graphics or Canvas Properties for Delphi Prism

Tags: graphics, delphi-prism, win32gui, font-replacement

Okay, instead of asking piece by piece, I am going to list all the canvas properties from win32 program that I am having problem with. What would you replace these with for Delphi Prism?

```
TPanelBevel
TFontStyles
TFontData
TDateTime
TColor
TBrushStyle
TAlignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Canvas in Windows Forms. There are some possible workarounds:
1.) You could start drawing on a Bitmap and display this Bitmap on your form. [Here is an example for that](http://hourlyapps.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-draw-on-windows-form-using-c-net.html) (in C# again).

2.) You could use a WPF canvas in your Windows Forms application (create it within an System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost control) and use this.

Besides this, there is no direct way to work with a canvas-style element in .NET.

Comment: Actually I meant to ask question about Graphics not necessarily about Canvas.

Comment: You will find all things for that in the System.Drawing namespace.